# when i try to call insert function in main it is not take the numbers?

Tags: c++, stack, binary-tree

```
eleman* insert( eleman* agac, int eklenecekDeger)
{
// ağacımız tamamen boş ise
if (agac == NULL)
{
    // kökümüzü oluşturuyoruz
    eleman* kok = (eleman*)malloc(sizeof(eleman));

    // kökümüzün sağı ve solunu boş olacakları için NULL yapıyoruz
    kok->right = NULL;
    kok->left = NULL;

    // eklenecek değerimizi ekliyoruz
    kok->key = eklenecekDeger;
    cout << eklenecekDeger<<endl;
    // ve yeni kök değerimizi geriye döndürüyoruz
    return kok;
}

// eklenecek değer kökten büyükse sağ alt ağaca geçip
// fonksiyonumuzu orada tekrar işliyoruz (özyineleme)
if (agac->key < eklenecekDeger)
{
    agac->right = insert(agac->right, eklenecekDeger);
}
else // değer kökten küçükse sol alt ağaca geçiyoruz
{
    agac->left = insert(agac->left, eklenecekDeger);
}
cout << "eklenen eleman" ;
// ağacımızın son halini geriye döndürüyoruz
return agac;
}
```

This func is for insert new number to a binary tree.But when i call it in main like this

```
int dizi[MAXSIZE];
    for (int i = mystack.top; i >= 0; i--) {
        //dizi[i] = pop();
        //insert(agac, dizi[i]);
        insert(agac, pop());
        inorder(agac);
    }
```

it is not working.This program is going to take numbers from stack and put them in binary tree.

Comment: Unfortunately "*is not working*" is not a very meaningful trouble report.  Which behaviour do you observe, that does not satisfy which of your expectations?

Comment: Code, input, observed output, expected output. Identifiers and comments in English (the *lingua franca* of programming). And make it a [mcve]. (Seriously. Follow that link, and read it. It is good advice in general, and will make your life here on StackOverflow in particular *much* easier...)

Comment: this for loop is taking numbers from integer with pop() then my insert func add them to tree. That is what i'm waiting. but insert func does not doing that. I have a inorder func too. When i call inorder i get "tree is empty" output

Comment: This looks like C not C++. In C++ You should use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: @DevSolar thanks im gonna try improve my question

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: For C++, the OP should be using smartpointers... but I guess this one's following the (very flawed, IMHO) "learn C first" approach.

Comment: [Introduction to debugging in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/08/11/introduction-to-debugging/). Even though it is for Visual Studio, the basics are all the same for every IDE (even dating back to Turbo C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is working correctly.

As can be noticed the insert returns a new head.
And in the test You are not storing it!

It should look like this:

```
for (int i = mystack.top; i >= 0; i--) {
    //dizi[i] = pop();
    //insert(agac, dizi[i]);
    agac = insert(agac, pop());
    inorder(agac);
}
```

In C++ `new` should be used instead of `malloc`.

If this is C++ 11 then the function should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.
Like this:

```
if (agac == nullptr)
{
    eleman* kok = new eleman;

    kok->right = nullptr;
    kok->left  = nullptr;

    kok->key = eklenecekDeger;
    cout << eklenecekDeger << endl;

    return kok;
}
```